# How to replace ALL keys in java map?

Tags: java, dictionary, iterator, addition

I want to replace keys in my map.

I have the following code:

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("a", "1");
map.put("b", "2");
map.put("c", "3");
map.put("d", "4");
map.put("e", "5");
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Object>> iterator = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, Object> next = iterator.next();
    Object o = next.getValue();
    //how to add new element ?
    //...
    iterator.remove();
}
```

I want to achieve map with keys

```
a1->1
b2->2
c3->3
d4->4
e5->5
```

If I use in loop `map.put(next.getKey() + next.getValue(), next.getValue());` it will lead to `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: Do we have guarantee that new key doesn't already exist in map? Also are you facing any specific problem when writing your code?

Comment: Is this some kind of testing account that tracks the moderation of the forum?

Comment: @Pshemo yes it is guaranteed

Comment: @pandaadb really? Surely it will replace the previous *value*?

Comment: @arizzle concurrentModificationException

Comment: @pandaadb I need to replace keys (not values)

Comment: Do you must modify existing map? Or can you return new one with updated key-value pairs?

Comment: @Pshemo modifiyng looks better

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis answer you attach as duplicate contains answer how to replace 1 key(instead of all)

Comment: I changed duplicate target since your question was more detailed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid a `ConcurrentModificationException`, you need to add the new key/value pairs to a separate map, and then use `putAll` to add that map into the original one.

```
    Map<String, Object> newMap = new HashMap<>();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, Object> entry = iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();
        newMap.put(...);  // Whatever logic to compose new key/value pair.
    }
    map.putAll(newMap);
```